# Delete row from database using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP and a servlet which allow the user to add data in a database, then list the data. I would like to add, next to each row, a "Delete" button which would delete it from the database.

I already have a DAO to handle the delete part, but I am pretty new to JSP so I don't know how to create a button that would use this DAO. Should I create a second servlet? Or can I use the one I already have to handle the delete function? Here is my code :

JSP :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Utilisateurs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action=ServletUtilisateurs>
        <p>
            <label for="identifiant">Identifiant : </label>
            <input type="text" name="identifiant" id="identifiant" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Mot de passe : </label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="mail">Mail : </label>
            <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="nom">Nom : </label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="prenom">Prenom : </label>
            <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" />
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
    </form>

        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="utilisateur" items="${ utilisateurs }">
                <li>
                    <c:out value="${ utilisateur.identifiant }" />
                    <c:out value="${ utilisateur.password }" />
                    <c:out value="${ utilisateur.mail }" />
                    <c:out value="${ utilisateur.prenom }" />
                    <c:out value="${ utilisateur.nom }" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Supprimer" />
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet :

```
package org.escalade.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.escalade.beans.Utilisateur;
import org.escalade.dao.DaoFactory;
import org.escalade.dao.UtilisateurDao;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletUtilisateurs
 */
@WebServlet("/ServletUtilisateurs")
public class ServletUtilisateurs extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UtilisateurDao utilisateurDao;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        final DaoFactory daoFactory = DaoFactory.getInstance();
        this.utilisateurDao = daoFactory.getUtilisateurDao();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServletUtilisateurs() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final Utilisateur utilisateurs = new Utilisateur();
        request.setAttribute("utilisateurs", this.utilisateurDao.list());
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Utilisateurs.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur();

        utilisateur.setIdentifiant(request.getParameter("identifiant"));
        utilisateur.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        utilisateur.setMail(request.getParameter("mail"));
        utilisateur.setNom(request.getParameter("nom"));
        utilisateur.setPrenom(request.getParameter("prenom"));

        final Utilisateur utilisateurs = new Utilisateur();
        this.utilisateurDao.createUtilisateur(utilisateur);

        request.setAttribute("utilisateurs", this.utilisateurDao.list());

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Utilisateurs.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, your JSP will be used to render some HTML which is delivered to the user's browser. That means that the command to delete something (clicking the button) would need to be sent from the browser back to the server, i.e. you need to send a http request. That request would need to be handled by some servlet and that servlet would need to know what is has to do. The easiest way to do that would be to reuse your servlet and include some parameter(s) that say "delete x", e.g. something like `command=delete` and `id=id_of_the_line`.

Comment: You can follow the https://www.javatpoint.com/crud-in-jsp. Main idea is have link with id parameters id=${u.getId()}&&action=delete. Based on these parameters handle in servet. The example may help you.